# PHPexcel issues

Tags: php, excel

OK, now I read examples of phpexcel. As I understand there shouldn't be any other output on page, to make proper xls-file. I think so, because when I have

```
echo "some output and my form for query";
            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Administrator");
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Administrator");
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("test");
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("test");
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("test");

            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Hello');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
            // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

            // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
            header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
            header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
            header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
            header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
echo"some other code";
```

And get xls, it has warnings that it doen't have css links there and moreover it puts a lot of text except Hello world!, such as links in excel file.
It looks like this:
[image: Output in excel]

I can put all work with xls in other php file and get it with ajax, but how can I give results of query to this file? All queries should be in my main file, because I don't want to have multiple connections to database. How it is clear, what I want. Any advices?

Comment: You're right, you can't have echoed output, and send an Excel file to a browser for download in the same request, otherwise you're just corrupting the Excel format file so that MS Excel can't read it properly. You generate ___either___ HTML markup, ___or___ an Excel file in a single request, but not both.... this is not a PHPExcel issue, it's an http issue.... it would be the same if you had a request to generate an image file, or a pdf, or a zip archive of data.... only one filetype per request

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Any ideas how to solve problem?

Comment: The solution is to only send one response type with each request.... even if that means each request having to read the data from the database

Comment: So I should connect to  database with each export of xls and it's impossible to avoid this?

Comment: It's not possible to avoid it, because each export must be a separate request..... unless you somehow cache the data, or the generated Excel file, you need to retrieve that data again from the database each time.... same as you'd need to retrieve it for each html request

Answer (score 0):

To download xls(x) file, you have to set right headers and clean the buffer to avoid bad stream.
As documentation explains you can try with this code:

```
//------------- Enter your code before this line --------- //

// Cleaning buffer
ob_clean();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

/* Or you can use 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
*/

// redirect output to client browser
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="your_filename.xls"');
/* Use this for Writer Excel2007     
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="your_filename.xlsx"');
*/
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

//Start Download
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

You can refer [here](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/119187) for the Developers Documentation of PHPExcel